# Is it possible to find children elements whom's height exceeds certain value

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to find children elements whom's height exceeds certain value ?

What actually happening is that one of the child element is adding scroll to y-axis. I know I can use overflow-y: hidden but I want to keep it auto...

This is what I am trying,

```
$("#mainDiv").children().height > 500 ?
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML? It sounds like there should be a better solution to your problem using HTML and CSS alone. JS shouldn't be a crutch to fix UI problems.

Comment: HTML is confidential to share - I am sorry :(.

Comment: So create simple meta example. No one is asking you to reveal government secrets.

Comment: ok, let me try please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old school way...

```
var result = [];
getOverwidthChilds($('#mainDiv').children(), result, function() {
  console.log(result);
});

function getOverwidthChilds(elements, resultArray, callback) {
  if (elements !== undefined && elements.length > 0) {
    // noprotect
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      var element = elements[i];
      if ($(element).width() > 500) {
        resultArray.push($(element));
      }
      if ($(element).children().length > 0) {
        getOverwidthChilds($(element).children(), resultArray);
      }
    }
  }
  if (callback) {
    callback();
  }  
}
```

JSBin:
http://jsbin.com/hegusepumi/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `filter` method with a callback function. Like so:

```
var $tallElements = $('#mainDiv').children().filter(function() {
   return ($(this).height() > 500);
});
```